# ReactJS, Only last Item ID updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Can you give me an Idea to solve my error, when I update the data only last Item ID make change even I click the first ID.

**Modal**

```
<Modal
    size="lg"
    show={UpShow}
    onHide={() => setUpShow(false)}
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
    className={classes.modal}
    >
    <Modal.Body>
        <div className="modal-background-color">
             <PurchaseUpdate requestType="put" id={PurchaseData.id} />
        </div>
    </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

Everything is running good except the update, anyone have an idea please let me know.Thanks

```
POhandleformsubmit = (event, requestType, id) => {
    // event.preventDefault();
    const Item_no = event.target.elements.upItem_no.value;
    const Description = event.target.elements.upDescription.value;
    const Supplier = event.target.elements.upSupplier.value;
    const Unit_price = event.target.elements.upUnit_price.value;
    const Quantity = event.target.elements.upQuantity.value;

    console.log(Item_no, Description, Supplier, Unit_price, Quantity);

    switch (requestType) {
        case 'put':
            return axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Purchase/PO/${id}/`, {
                Item_no: Item_no,
                Description: Description,
                Supplier: Supplier,
                Unit_price: Unit_price,
                Quantity: Quantity

            })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-visvesvaraya-5b87b?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`UpShow` is a boolean (`const [UpShow, setUpShow] = useState(false);`) so when any single `PurchaseData` item toggles the value (`onClick={() => setUpShow(PurchaseData.id)}`) truthy then ***all*** modals toggle open (since they queue from the same single state value) and the last mapped `PurchaseData` item's modal is the top-most one visible. When the modal is toggled close, similarly, all modals close.

## Solution

Check the saved `PurchaseData.id` to open any specific modal.

```
<Modal
  size="lg"
  show={UpShow === PurchaseData.id} // <-- match saved id with the current mapped id
  onHide={() => setUpShow(false)}
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
  className={classes.modal}
>
  <Modal.Body>
    <div className="modal-background-color">
      <PurchaseUpdate
        requestType="put"
        id={PurchaseData.id}
      />
    </div>
  </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```